# Implementing stack without dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, stack

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node *n;
};

void push (Node *front, int value) {
    Node new;
    new.n = front;
    new.value = value;
    Node *newPtr = &new;
    front = newPtr;
}

int pop (Node *front) {
    int n = front->value;
    front = front->n;
    return n;
}
```

I tried to implement stack without dynamic memory allocation this way, but I failed to make it work. Any hints on what I should be doing to make it work?

Comment: You need to provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a description of what exactly did not work, including exact error message text and locations wherere they appear.

Comment: @Drop As pop function wasn't working (front node would not disappear), I assumed the design itself was already incorrect from the beginning.

Comment: Without MCVE my guesses: (1) `new` it is a reserved keyword in C++, you cannot use it as identifier name, (2) after `push()`, `front` is pointing to a temporary object that is destroyed when `push()` exits

Comment: Again, "not working" is not a constructive problem description. We will not be able to help you this way.

Comment: @Drop Oh that is my bad; I just used simple arbitrary variable name for this question only. I didn't actually use the name "new" in my program.

Comment: You should only post the code that you actually tried.

Comment: I'm really sorry; the second point you suggested seems to be the problem. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: @Drop The code I used is exactly identical to the one I posted, except different variable names.

Comment: First, you would probably want to pick a good book on C++: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @Drop I see, thank you for the advice!

Comment: Second, there are zillion of ways of implementing stack. Linked list implementation is hard to get right without heap memory, so you should think about some other possible implementations. For example, array-based contiguous implementation. Don't hesitate to Google, make some research. It's not that hard. Later you can return back to this question and post an answer yourself, so someone else might use this information in the future.

Comment: @Drop Alright, thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the address of a temporary variable.  In push, you make a local variable 'new', take the address of it, then when the function exits that's an invalid pointer.

You need to use dynamic memory allocation for this task if your solution is going to be robust.

Comment: The topic name is: "Implementing stack *without* dynamic memory allocation"

Comment: Yes.... but the program isn't up to that task.  Sometimes the answer is pointing out that you shouldn't do that. (An option would be to use a different data structure, a fixed array or something, but he clearly has a linked list structure.)

Comment: Well, stack *can* be implemented without heap. Robustly. And the answer is to not use linked list as underlying data structure or  to use stack-buffer-based allocator.